# Filesystem won't grant any space to my Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, persistent-storage, html5-filesystem

I'm working on a chrome extension and testing it as an unpacked extension.

I managed to get to the point where I can request a quota and request a filesystem, but it won't grant any space.

From the background.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function()
    {
        navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.queryUsageAndQuota(
            function(usedQuota, grantedQuota)
            {
                console.log(usedQuota + " of " + grantedQuota);
            }
        );
        let requestedBytes = 1024 * 1024 * 10; //10mb
        navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota(
            requestedBytes,
            function(grantedBytes)
            {
                window.webkitRequestFileSystem(
                    PERSISTENT,
                    grantedBytes,
                    function (filesystem)
                    {
                        console.log("Name: " + filesystem.name);
                        console.log("Requested Size " + (requestedBytes / 1024 / 1024))
                        console.log("Granted Size: " + (grantedBytes / 1024 / 1024));
                    },
                    function (fileerror) {console.log("Error: " + fileerror);}
                )
            }
        );
    }
);
```

I have an index.html that sends a message, which activates the above code.

But this is all I can get it to output:

```
0 of 0
background.js:29 Name: chrome-extension_dpgmepaclcikglfooaopnbockbeenlbd_0:Persistent
background.js:30 Requested Size 10
background.js:31 Granted Size: 0
```

manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "SomeRandomName",
    "version": "0.1",
    "browser_action":
    {
    },
    "permissions":
    [
    ],
    "background":
    {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'sha256-d8KCEnecXtiRMS4Kj2vm8/UElPKEk5YsgZWRWitb0O8='; object-src 'self'" //debug
}
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Try adding `"unlimitedStorage"` in `permissions`. It's also possible there's a bug in Chrome.

Comment: ...that worked. I thought you're not supposed to need that if you don't go beyond a certain amount.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently putting "unlimitedStorage" in permissions fixes it. But I thought there was a way to do it without asking for unlimited storage.